# Website shows secure on browser, but unsecure (without SSL certifcate) in mobile

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, web, browser, hosting

I think I successfully installed SSL certificate to my website, it shows secure on browser:

[image]

but when I open website in chrome mobile browser, it says:

```
Your connection to this site is not secure

You should not enter any sensitive information on this site ....
```

Is there any problem installing SSL certificate. I restarted my mobile, deleted all cookies, stories :( and still same thing. Any clue?

update: Server side configuration

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name IP_Address domain_name.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: This should be posted at SuperUser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the URL in the address bar of your mobile web browser from `http://...` to `https://...`.

If that fixes the problem, you will need to create a redirect that automatically does this for your visitors.

Comment: Thank you @WilliamB96, it worked fine! but I am redirecting the user to https:///, I must update answer in a min

Comment: @BasirPayenda Probably because $server_name is empty. Try using $host instead, or hardcode your domain, like this: `return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;`